# Google Cloud Run known issue: path ending with a z

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I was just doing some research into Google's Cloud Run service and happened to spot an issue where it says:

> It is not possible to use the following URL paths:
>
> Paths starting with `/_ah/`. Some paths ending with `z`

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#ah

Does that mean if my app happens to make a URL that ends with a `z`, like `/z` or `/xyz`, it will break?! That can't be right, surely. Does anyone using Cloud Run know anything about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few very specific top-level paths that Cloud Run reserves which all end in `z`. If your application with a specific path that ends in `z` is producing 404s for that path, it might be due to this.

Usually a path selected by the user doesn't conflict with this. The `/z` and `/xyz` paths are not reserved, for example.

Comment: Interesting. Though the word 'usually' isn't entirely reassuring :) In my case, it ... should ... not be an issue as I'm generating a random ID. My concern reading that was the 1/26 chance of it ending in a z and so 1/26 randomly not working because of this issue. So I should be fine. As my random ID won't match an internal Google URL. I would assume.